# Wordpress setting API strucked

Tags: admin-menu, settings-api

The entire day today I remained frustrated with few things. I am learning WordPress setting API from a Video Course offered by Team Tree House. I was watching Videos and writing the codes ditto, but have an issue at one point.

I am reproducing functions.php file code here

→

```
function wpt_theme_init() {
    register_setting( 'wptsettings-group', 'wpt_settings' );
    add_settings_section(
        'wpt_slideshow_section',
        'Slideshow Settings',
        'wpt_slideshow_section_callback',
        'general'
    );
    add_settings_field(
        'wpt_slideshow_checkbox',
        'Show slideshow on homepage',
        'wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback',
        'general',
        'wpt_slideshow_section'
    );
}

// Create Theme Options Page
function wpt_add_theme_page() {

    add_theme_page(
        __('Theme Options', 'wpsettings'),
        __('Theme Options', 'wpsettings'),
        'edit_theme_options',
        'wptsettings',
        'wpt_theme_options_page'
    );

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpt_add_theme_page');
function wpt_theme_options_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">

    <h2>Theme Options - <?php echo get_current_theme(); ?></h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        settings_fields( 'wptsettings-group' );
        do_settings_sections( 'wptsettings' );
        submit_button();
    ?>

</div>

<?php
}


// Enqueue theme styles
function wpt_theme_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_theme_styles' );

?>
```

I have crossed checked multiple times, but the issue is that I am unable to see this in my admin page. I should gete this[image]

But I am getting this.[image]

Couldn't find since morning hats going wrong.

In short this part is not completely working →

```
<div class="wrap">

    <h2>Theme Options - <?php echo get_current_theme(); ?></h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        settings_fields( 'wptsettings-group' );
        do_settings_sections( 'wptsettings' );
    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Missing few Things. 
First of all hook the function `wpt_theme_init` with `admin_init` or similar one. otherwise your function will not execute. example below

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpt_theme_init' );
```

`add_settings_section` and `add_settings_field` take 4th argument as a `$page` parameter. which is `wptsettings` in your case. remember? you have named your page `wptsettings` in `add_theme_page` ( 4th paramater ). so all these values must match.

Incorrect

```
add_settings_section(
    'wpt_slideshow_section',
    'Slideshow Settings',
    'wpt_slideshow_section_callback',
    'general'
);
add_settings_field(
    'wpt_slideshow_checkbox',
    'Show slideshow on homepage',
    'wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback',
    'general',
    'wpt_slideshow_section'
);
```

Correct

```
add_settings_section(
    'wpt_slideshow_section',
    'Slideshow Settings',
    'wpt_slideshow_section_callback',
    'wptsettings'
);
add_settings_field(
    'wpt_slideshow_checkbox',
    'Show slideshow on homepage',
    'wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback',
    'wptsettings',
    'wpt_slideshow_section'
);
```

Lastly you've not defined callback functions for section and field. this is required.

```
wpt_slideshow_section_callback
wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback
```

Section and field callback functions.

```
function wpt_slideshow_section_callback() {}
function wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback() {

$setting = esc_attr( get_option( 'wpt_settings' ) );
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="wpt_settings" value="1"<?php checked( 1 == $setting ); ?> />
<?php
```

}

The complete correct code for your admin page displaying checkbox.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpt_theme_init' );
function wpt_theme_init() {
    register_setting( 'wptsettings-group', 'wpt_settings' );
    add_settings_section(
        'wpt_slideshow_section',
        'Slideshow Settings',
        'wpt_slideshow_section_callback',
        'wptsettings'
    );
    add_settings_field(
        'wpt_slideshow_checkbox',
        'Show slideshow on homepage',
        'wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback',
        'wptsettings',
        'wpt_slideshow_section'
    );
}
function wpt_slideshow_section_callback() {}
function wpt_slideshow_checkbox_callback() {
$setting = esc_attr( get_option( 'wpt_settings' ) );
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="wpt_settings" value="1"<?php checked( 1 == $setting ); ?> />
<?php
}
// Create Theme Options Page
function wpt_add_theme_page() {

    add_theme_page(
        __('Theme Options', 'wpsettings'),
        __('Theme Options', 'wpsettings'),
        'manage_options',
        'wptsettings',
        'wpt_theme_options_page'
    );

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpt_add_theme_page');
function wpt_theme_options_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">

    <h2>Theme Options - <?php echo wp_get_theme(); ?></h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        settings_fields( 'wptsettings-group' );
        do_settings_sections( 'wptsettings' );
        submit_button();
    ?>

</div>

<?php
}
```

Let me know if its working or need more help?

Comment: Oh Boss You made my day. You could not believe how much frustrated and depressed I was for the entire day. as soon as I changed     'general',
 to 'wptsettings' everything seems to be in order. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: glad to hear that. you're welcome